# Как в данном слайдере вывести ссылку на категорию, что бы она не повторялась?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

[Ссылка на шаблон](http://www.restudio.com.ua/livepreview?demo=35965).

Слайдер: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот код этого слайдера:

```
<div class="wpc-team s-back-switch swip-wrap">
    <div class="container no-padding full-width-md">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="team-slider-wrapper">
                    <div class="wpc-team-slider">
                        <img src="img/team-bg.jpg" alt="" class="s-img-switch">
                        <div class="swiper-container" data-loop="1" data-speed="1000" data-slides-per-view="responsive" data-xs-slides="1" data-sm-slides="2" data-md-slides="3" data-lg-slides="3" data-add-slides="3">
                            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <?php foreach ($our_directory as $value): ?>
                            <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="" data-desc="Suspendisse non lectus sit amet dolor eleifend vehicula. Praesent placerat purus ut tempor elementum. Suspendisse viverra aliquam ultrices. Mauris id odio eu nunc facilisis cursus a eu sem. Ut mollis orci quis mauris pulvinar, sit amet mattis quam tempus. Aliquam iaculis velit sit amet feugiat porta. Donec velit nisl, commodo sed augue id, luctus cursus felis. Mauris diam neque, vehicula et lacus in, tempus fermentum felis. Aliquam sed eleifend felis, eu ultrices leo. Sed tortor erat, facilisis et libero non, porta pellentesque lorem."></a>
                                    <!-- swiper slide -->
                                    <div class="wrapper-img">
                                        <div class="img-wrap s-back-switch">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>"><img src="admin/<?php echo $value['url_img'] ?>" alt="" class="s-img-switch"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pagination"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wpc-swiper-arrow arrow-left swip-arrow-left classic light wpc-romb">
                            <i class="flaticon-back"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wpc-swiper-arrow arrow-right swip-arrow-right classic light wpc-romb">
                            <i class="flaticon-next"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                <section class="wrap-info text-center text-right-md">
        <?php foreach ($our_directory as $value): ?>
                    <a href="articles.php?type=articles&id=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>"><h1 class="title team-title margin-lg-35b"><?php echo $value['title'] ?></h1></a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Если поставить в `data-title="<?php echo $value['title'] ?>"`, то все работает, но нужна ссылка, а если ее поставить в `data-title`, то слайдер ломается. Я обрамил `foreach` и в нем сделал ссылку вокруг `H1`. Так работает, только теперь показывает сразу 2 названия рубрики, думаю это из за второго `foreach`. Но иначе не хочет работать. А если использовать один `foreach` и поместить в него весь блок слайдера то верстка ломается но работает. Что можно сделать в данном случае? Как то странно слайдер сделан. С тем слайдером что по выше проблем не было. Хотя там тоже есть атрибут `data`.

Answer (score 0):

```
div class="swiper-slide"
```

там после его объявления есть закрывающий тег `/a`
уберите

Comment: Это когда я делал, случайно оставил, но это не помогло. Если поставить в первый data-title="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" то все работает но никуда не переходит, нужна ссылка и если ее добавить то слайдер ломается. А если добавить в h1 что в самом низу то работает но показывает сразу все рубрики.

На счет двух data-title я что то напутал, он один. Но data-title и h1 внизу как то связаны.